# Three JS GPU lag with Fragment Shader and Scene change

Tags: reactjs, three.js, gpu, webgl

I am working on a ThreeJs program that previews different Shaders from ShaderToys.
The app creates one Plane Mesh and populates it with a Fragment Shader. The Fragment shaders can be vary complex and overpowers the GPU.

When I change the scene using "prev" and "next" it seems like the state of the animations is saving. As opposed to when I reload the page.

When I reload the page on different animations, all run smoothly without lag. It is only when I change scenes.

** What I've Tried**

1. Calling `dispose()` on Materials, Geometry, and Textures after scene change.
2. Cleaning WebGL's renderer Buffer.
3. Clearing animation Timeouts.

**What I think is happening**

I think the fragment shaders imported into the Plane Mesh are still being processed by the GPU even after the scene change.

Does anyone know how I can better understand what's causing the high GPU usage?

THanks

**Here is the code**

```
class App extends Component {
  ...

  componentDidUpdate = () => {
    if (scene) {
      this.clearThree();
      clearTimeout(animateTimeout);
      clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
    }
    timeouts++;
    this.startVisual();

  };
  clearThree = () => {
    for (var i = scene.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      let obj = scene.children[i];

      obj.geometry.dispose();
      obj.material.dispose();
      // disposeTexture(obj.material)

      scene.remove(obj);
    }
  };

  startVisual = async () => {
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(animate);

    let shader = this.props.shader;
    const canvas = this.props.canvas;

    if (!renderer) {
      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas });
    } else {
      renderer.clear();
    }

    const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(...);

    if (canvas) {
      createScene();
      animateTimeout = setTimeout(() => animate(), 144 / 1000);
    }


    function createScene() {
      if (!scene) {
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
      }
      const plane = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(2, 2);

      uniforms = {
        iTime: { value: 0 },
        iResolution: { value: new THREE.Vector3() },
        iChannel0: {
          value: new THREE.DataTexture(...)
        },
        iChannel1: {
          value: new THREE.DataTexture(...)
        },
        iChannel2: {
          value: new THREE.DataTexture(...)
        },
        iChannel3: {
          value: new THREE.DataTexture(...)
        }
      };

      const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        fragmentShader: shader,  // This contains GLSL code
        uniforms
      });

      scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(plane, material));
    }

    function animate(time) {

      animateTimeout = setTimeout(
        () => requestAnimationFrame(animate),
        144 / 1000
      );

      resizeTimeout = setTimeout(
        () => resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer, canvas),
        144 / 1000
      );

      analyser.getByteFrequencyData(audioData);

      time *= 0.001;

      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <div />;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Could be a number of things. Let's see your code, or a working demo would be even better.

Comment: thank for the advice. I added some code

Comment: I'd run a memory profile on this code. It looks like you're creating/recreating a lot of objects and functions that you don't need to.

Comment: You might also want to include a tag for the framework you're using. It's likely not relevant in the long run, but there may be other considerations regarding memory/process allocation depending on the system.

Comment: How did you go with this issue @PaulTrimor? I'm facing the same problem and I was wondering if you were able to find a solution to the problem and if you could share it with me?